Building angular library in standalone keeps getting error in public-api file
I've recently find micro frontend projects building and im working on latest angular v.17 standalone project, but when i create lib module and build it fresh. it keeps getting error in public-api.
ERROR:

Application bundle generation failed. [0.091 seconds]

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "../../../../dist/test/public-api"

    src/app/layout/standard/standard.component.ts:2:30:
      2 │ import { TestComponent } from '../../../../dist/test/public-api';
        ╵                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Steps I did ->
ng g lib test
ng build test --watch
And I import Build to StandardComponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from '../../service/base.service';
import { TestComponent } from '../../../../dist/test/public-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-standard',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TestComponent],
  templateUrl: './standard.component.html',
  styleUrl: './standard.component.scss'
})
export class StandardComponent {

}

StandardComponent HTML ->
<p>standard works!</p>
<lib-test></lib-test>


Why are you trying to import it from dist (build)?

It automatically imported from build path.

Try removing that import and check if there is a suggestion without /dist in it

There's option for dev path.. ./project/lib/ but i want to use build library module
